# Eclipse 4 and RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to do the [eclipse tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) from the vogella website. I'm getting the following errors, when I try to create a new application:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:340)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.getText(Text.java:1327)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewProjectCreationPage.getProjectNameFieldValue(WizardNewProjectCreationPage.java:296)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewProjectCreationPage.getProjectName(WizardNewProjectCreationPage.java:282)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewProjectCreationPage.getProjectHandle(WizardNewProjectCreationPage.java:267)
at org.eclipse.e4.internal.tools.wizards.project.E4NewProjectWizard$1.getProject(E4NewProjectWizard.java:121)
at org.eclipse.e4.internal.tools.wizards.project.E4NewProjectWizard.performFinish(E4NewProjectWizard.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:259)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:229)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:500)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I also have this error:

```
Resource '/com.example.e4.rcp.wizard/plugin.xml' already exists
```

I use Eclipse for RCP and RAP developers Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20120920-0800 on windows 7 64 bit,

Can somebody tell me, where the problem is?

Comment: Do you already have this project in your workspace com.example.e4.rcp.wizard ? Also are you using Eclipse Juno Sr1?

Answer (score 0):

Possible Duplicate : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144590/org-eclipse-swt-swtexception-widget-is-disposed-from-table-refresh)

Try to follow the second suggestion:

> Create new Workspace

..as you have plugin error too.